# "Primary script unknown" across subvol/dataset of Btrfs/ZFS

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

When I use nginx together with php-fpm and try to access a file which is not on the same subvol/dataset as `/` then it will result in:

```
[error] 27411#27411: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

I first noticed this with Btrfs, but now that I started using ZFS, it has the same problem. For example say that `/home/user` is in a separate dataset, and I have configured nginx with `root /home/user/domains/example.com;` then trying to access say `example.com/test.php` will result in `Primary script unknown`, even though `/home/user/domains/example.com/test.php` exists.

I know it has to do with accessing the file across datasets or something close to it, because if instead I run `mount --bind /home/user /fix` and change the nginx config to `root /fix/domains/example.com;`, it all works (error gone and PHP runs).

I tried solving this in the past, but so far have been unable to, only this `mount --bind` workaround has worked so far. Does anybody have any idea what could be the cause of this and how I might solve it without the workaround? I assume it is caused by some security measure that prevents accessing other partitions, but I am unaware of any FastCGI or php-fpm setting that allows me to change this policy.